# SAP Char.Value Description not in CAWNT

Tags: class, sap-erp, characteristics

I'm running into a bit of a problem when trying to lookup/create a report showing characteristic value descriptions.

My issue is that some of our characteristics are created with Datatype = `NUM` (via tcode `CT04`) and I can easily find these in table `CAWN` but I don't find the actual value description which is usually present in `CAWNT`.

Any idea why and/or if SAP ERP stores the value description in another table when Datatype = `NUM` ?

(FYI - there's no problem when Datatype = `CHAR`)

Br,
Thomas

```
[CT04 screenshot - basic][1]
[CT04 screenshot - values][2]
[table CAWN screenshot - values][3]
```

Comment: There is no description for NUM values in `CT04`, it's why you don't find any table (because nothing can be entered, nothing can be stored). It looks like an invalid question?

Comment: show us with screenshots what you create and how

Comment: I'll try to add some screenshots - maybe I should clarify a bit - I do get data populated in CABN, CABNT and CAWN - but nothing in CAWNT (nor in AUSP) - I'm therefore wondering how I can show in the report which value have been selected for the material

Answer (score 0):

See my accepted response on SAP Q&A: [SAP Char.Value Description not in CAWNT](https://answers.sap.com/questions/13541508/sap-charvalue-description-not-in-cawnt.html?childToView=13541625)